# Simple (I think) Horizontal Line in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Creating a relatively simple data entry form, and just want to separate certain sections with a horizontal line (not unlike an HR tag in HTML) that stretches the full length of the form.

I have tried this:

```
<Line Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" X2="1"/>
```

Because the parent control is not a fixed width, this line causes the window to stretch to the full width of the screen.

Is there an easy way to do this without fixing the width of my parent control/window?

Comment: The answer is [here][1].
I prefer the answer of mletterle.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011571/a-vertical-seperator-control-in-a-menu-toolbar-stackpanel-etc-is-it-possib

Answer (score 615, accepted):

How about add this to your xaml:

```
<Separator/>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is a solution. I add a separator and I don't see any line. What configuration is necessary when placing the separator within a standard layout panel such as a Grid to get it to show up like a horizontal rule?

Comment: I agree, it appears that this does not work for some controls

Comment: I added a height and background color to the separator when it did not show.

Comment: @jpierson If you add it to a grid, you probably need to assign it to a row and column like any other control. Otherwise it will probably appear in the first row/col, and you will miss it. (It works properly on a StackPanel.)

Comment: that's correct, need to assign the row/column, or probably column span.

Comment: Please note that `<Separator/>` will be read-out-loud by screen readers. If `<Separator/>` is used to actually separate groups of items in the UI, this is a perfect solution.
Where the use of line has purely aesthetical reasons, I'd suggest using `<Line/>` or `<Rectangle/>` instead.

Comment: This was not available for me in UWP.

Comment: This is not available in a .Net Core 3.1 wpf app.

Comment: I'd downvote this to a 0 becuase the op asks for WPF horizontal lines: & a seperator is vertical

Comment: @JRrelyea, my separator came exactly horizontal.

Comment: The seperator tag is vertical, never horizontal. Sorry. Are you also rotating it 90 degrees in XAML?

Answer (score 90):

I had the same issue and eventually chose to use a Rectangle element:

`<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue" Height="4"/>`

In my opinion it's somewhat easier to modify/shape than a separator.
Of course the `Separator` is a very easy and neat solution for simple separations :)

Comment: Works in Silverlight 5 whereas `Seperator` does not.

Answer (score 18):

Use a Border of height 1 and don't set the Width (i.e. Width = Auto, HorizontalAlignment = Stretch, the default)

Comment: It's handy for vertical separators anyway: `<Border Width="1" Margin="2" Background="#8888"/>`

Comment: Personally, my favourite solution

Answer (score 15):

For anyone else struggling with this: [Qwertie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314975/simple-i-think-horizontal-line-in-wpf#comment18701114_2314986) worked well for me.

```
<Border Width="1" Margin="2" Background="#8888"/>
```

This creates a vertical seperator which you can talior to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
To draw Horizontal 
************************    
<Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="DarkCyan" Height="4"/>

To draw vertical 
*******************
 <Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="DarkCyan" Height="4" Width="Auto" >
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
```

Comment: Why not do this?

`<Rectangle  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="DarkCyan" Width="4"/> `

Answer (score 1):

1st, the op asked for a horizontal line. seperators are vertical (not sure how that got so many up votes---they're not horizontal)

Play around using a simple line tag

```
<Line
Grid.Row="4"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
StrokeThickness="1"
X1="0"
X2="300"
Y1="10"
Y2="10" />
```

That's a horizontal line. Play around with the X & Y axis to make it work...simple enough to make a horizontal, vertical or any other angled line segment that doesn't resize a window