# A vertical Separator control in a Menu, Toolbar, StackPanel, etc. - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, toolbar, separator

I want to use the Separator control in a vertical way (Lets say in a horizontal StackPanel).

Searching around I found this method but it doesn't use the Separator control rather it uses borders and rectangles.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/eab865be-ad9b-45ed-b9d8-fc93f737b163

Is it possible to use the Separator control in a vertical way?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Also:

```
<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
```

Answer (score 34):

Vertical Separator

```
<Style x:Key="VerticalSeparatorStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Separator}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,0,6,0"/>
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TransformGroup.Children>
                    <TransformCollection>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    </TransformCollection>
                </TransformGroup.Children>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Which can be used like this

```
<Separator Style="{DynamicResource VerticalSeparatorStyle}" />
```