# Is there any "line with text" control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just need to separate two grous of buttons inside StackPanel with something like:

```
---------Another Buttons--------
```

but I need a solid line, note --

Comment: use a groupbox for that

Comment: I dont need bottom and corner borders - only top

Comment: Did you try searching for something like *[separator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13584998/1997232)*? And text can be layouted on top of it (inside parent container, e.g. `Grid`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom control for this.

The code for the Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LineControl}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LineControl}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Separator Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Separator>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    <Separator Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Separator>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The C# code:

```
public class LineControl : ContentControl
{
    static LineControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LineControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LineControl)));
    }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
<local:LineControl>
    <TextBlock>test</TextBlock>
</local:LineControl>
```

The TextBlock can be any control. You can even put a StackPanel with buttons in it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />            
</StackPanel>
```

try this

Comment: wonderfull, but how to place a text in the middle of this line?

Comment: I have used TextBlock with Alt code 196 (─) char ..  this is ugly but works