# WPF how to put separator below each item in horizontal stackpanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, stackpanel

I've got a horizontal stackpanel on which I add items. I would like to add a separator below each project name, rather than it being to the right of the name, and that separator should span the whole page. These 2 questions haven't helped me up to now: [How to add a vertical Separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584998/how-to-add-a-vertical-separator)    [How can a separator be added between items in an ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511227/how-can-a-separator-be-added-between-items-in-an-itemscontrol)

[image]

The View code is:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" Margin="49,188,54,0">
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource  Appbar_Suitcase}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the inner `StackPanel`? Just one `StackPanel` and putting all three elements inside?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I just tried it, updated question too. But problem still persists, meaning separator is vertical, and to the right of the project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the first stackpanel vertical and put the content control and the label inside of a horizontal stackpanel. something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl  Content="{StaticResource  Appbar_Suitcase}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
</StackPanel>
```