# What is the correct way to add a vertical separator in a WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to add a vertical separator of some kind in a WPF XAML ListView.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="10" x:Name="seperator">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" Margin="-6,-2,-6,-2">
                <Grid Background="Black" Margin="-1, -14, -1, -14"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

It feels like it should be easier to either fill the background of the column or set a border on the right/left.
The results I've found seem to be dynamic or for rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A vertical Separator control in a Menu, Toolbar, StackPanel, etc. - Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011571/a-vertical-separator-control-in-a-menu-toolbar-stackpanel-etc-is-it-possib)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will create a vertical separator using default ToolBar style, but you can use your own style if you prefer.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: For [MahApps](https://mahapps.com/), one can use: `<Separator " Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Separator.StatusBar}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use border

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Grey" Width="1" Margin="10,0" />
</Grid>
```